# Heat map and datetime axis

Tags: highcharts

Is it possible to use datetime axis in a heat map?

```
xAxis: {
        type: 'datetime',
    },
```

How should I define the timestamp in the data? how can I define the min value and the max value?

```
series: [{
        name: 'Sales per employee',
        borderWidth: 1,
        data: [[0, 0, 10],  [1, 0, 92],   
               //HOW SHOULD I PUSH TIMESTAMP?
        ],
```

http://jsfiddle.net/fuw65g95/9/

Comment: Use `colsize`, just like in [this example](http://www.highcharts.com/maps/demo/heatmap).

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/fuw65g95/11/ :S whats going on with the colour and the xAxis? If I define x:Date.UTC(2013, 07, 10) it crashes

Comment: How about demo prepared by Pawel?

Comment: Yes, the default one is always nice, the problem is when I try to do something a little bit different. I wasnt using datetime, I was pushing the dates to xAxisCategory, the problem is when different rows have different number of dates (xAxisCategories). I am trying to solve it this way but still... is it possible to give a time interval?

Comment: This is what I get: http://jsfiddle.net/fuw65g95/13/